# Help Linqifying collection to Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I'm refactoring this code and was trying to think of a simple linq expression to populate this Dictionary.

```
IEnumerable<IHeaderRecord> headers = PopulateHeaders();
var headerLocationLookup = new Dictionary<string, IHeaderRecord>();

foreach (var header in headers)
{
//destination locations can repeat, if they do, dictionary should only contain the first header associated with a particular location
    if (!headerLocationLookup.ContainsKey(header.DestinationLocation)) 
    {
         headerLocationLookup[header.DestinationLocation] = header;
    }
}
```

I could only come up with implementing a custom IEqualityComparer and using that in an expression such as this...

```
headers.Distinct(new CustomComparer()).ToDictionary();
```

Is there a way to do it all inline without the custom IEqualityComparer?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    var qry = headers.GroupBy(row => row.DestinationLocation)
        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First());
```

or (equivalent):

```
    var dictionary = (from row  in headers
              group row by row.DestinationLocation)
              .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First());
```

I wonder, though, if your current `foreach` code isn't already better - it doesn't buffer the ones it intends to drop, for example.

Comment: Good answer.  I think you are right that the current code is more clear.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a [blog post](http://gregbeech.com/blog/from-projections-to-comparers) a while back that shows you how you can create overloads of Distinct that use a lambda expression as the key selector instead of a custom comparer, which would let you write:

```
headers.Distinct(h => h.DestinationLocation)
       .ToDictionary(h => h.DestinationLocation);
```

It does use a custom comparer underneath, but the extension method constructs that stuff for you, and makes it much easier to read.

Comment: That it very pleasing on the eye.

Answer (score 2):

```
var headerLocationLookup = PopulateHeaders()
    .Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, IHeaderRecord>(), (header, d) => {
        if(d.ContainsKey(header.DestinationLocation)) 
            d[header.DestinationLocation] = header;

        return d;
    });
```

I don't think this is any clearer than the existing code though.